# MySQL query in Sequelize ORM with foreign key

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

I have this query,

```
UPDATE physics_tbls SET Level_id =
   (SELECT level_id FROM level_tbl WHERE Level = 'Higher') 
WHERE id = 192;
```

which I need to find the  Sequelize equivalent for.

So to explain, I have a table physics_tbls in which there is a field Level_id which has a foreign key to the field Level in another table called level_tbls.

When I update Level_id I need to do a SELECT on 'Higher' in the level_tbls table to see what id should go in for Level_id

Should I be using 'through' as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48525376/4001324)?

I can't make much sense of [this](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/associations.html#belongsto).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use raw queries

```
sequelize.query("UPDATE physics_tbls SET Level_id = (SELECT level_id FROM level_tbl WHERE Level = 'Higher') WHERE id = 192;").then(([results, metadata]) => {
  // Results will be an empty array and metadata will contain the number of affected rows.
})
```

or

A subquery can be done like this...

```
physics_tbls.update(
    { Level_id : [clout.sequelize.literal("SELECT level_id FROM level_tbl WHERE Level = 'Higher'"))] }, 
    { where: { _id: 192 } }
).then(result => handleResult(result))
 .catch(err => handleError(err))
```

Reference:

- [Query: Basics](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/querying.html#basics)
- [Raw Queries](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/raw-queries.html)

Comment: Thank you very much and I didn't realise you could put raw sql into sequelize like that. Very useful, thanks again for your help

Comment: Don't we all overlook something sometimes. Happy to help :)

Comment: This post has helped a lot but I have a follow on question posted here https://stackoverflow.com/q/57739619/4001324